# SQL Oracle query to find employees first job & avg salary with company and last(or current) job & avg salary with company

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**I am trying to return columns for**

•   **Employee ID** for all employees whether they have had just one job or
    many jobs

•   **Job ID** for their **first Job** (the first one in the job_history table or the one in the employees table if they have only had one job)

•   **average salary** for that job

•   **Job ID** for their **most recent** job (The one indicated in the employee table)

• **average salary** for that job

• **employees current salary**

**TABLES**

**HR.JOBS**

```
Name       Null     Type         
---------- -------- ------------ 
JOB_ID     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
JOB_TITLE  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(35) 
MIN_SALARY          NUMBER(6)    
MAX_SALARY          NUMBER(6)
```

**HR.EMPLOYEES**

```
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)    
GENDER                  CHAR(1)
```

**HR.JOB_HISTORY**

```
Name          Null     Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
START_DATE    NOT NULL DATE         
END_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
DEPARTMENT_ID          NUMBER(4)
```

**Here is what I have so far**

```
    SELECT a.employee_id, a.job_id, a.current_avg_earnings, a.salary,
         NVL(to_char(a.previous_avg_earnings),'same') previous_avg_earnings
FROM
(SELECT e.employee_id, e.job_id, 
  (SELECT SUM(j.max_salary+j.min_salary)/2
FROM hr.jobs j
WHERE j.job_id = e.job_id) AS current_avg_earnings, salary,
  (SELECT SUM(j.max_salary+j.min_salary)/2
FROM hr.job_history h
JOIN hr.jobs j ON h.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE h.employee_id = e.employee_id AND h.job_id = e.job_id)
AS previous_avg_earnings
FROM hr.employees e
) a;
```

**sample rows**

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_JOB_ID AVG_1 CURRENT_JOB_ID AVG_2 SALARY
----------- ------------ ----- -------------- ----- ------
0001        MAILCLERK    2400  SAME           SAME   2900
0002        MACHINETECH  4800  ENGINEER       9800   10500
0003        CASHIER      2300  SECRETARY      4500   5500
0004        MANAGER      9900  SAME           SAME   12500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first CTE, `u`, collect current `employee_id, salary, job_id` from the `employees` table, and `union all` with `employee_id, (current) salary, first job_id` from joining `employees` to `job_history`. Preparing for a pivot later on, add a column `status` to distinguish `c`urrent from `f`irst. Then in the second CTE, `p`, join the result of this union to the `jobs` table to get the average for each job (both "first" and "current"). Then pivot to separate "first" from "current" - and, in the select, where the pivot would create NULL for the "first" columns, use `nvl()` to populate with the current values instead.

```
with 
     u ( employee_id, salary, job_id, status ) as (
       select employee_id, salary, job_id, 'c'
         from employees
       union all
       select e.employee_id, e.salary,
              min(jh.job_id) keep (dense_rank first order by jh.start_date), 'f'
         from employees e inner join job_history jh
                          on e.employee_id = jh.employee_id
         group by e.employee_id, e.salary
     ),
     p ( employee_id, salary, job_id, status, avg_salary ) as (
       select u.employee_id, u.salary, u.job_id, u.status,
              (j.min_salary + j.max_salary) / 2
       from   u inner join jobs j on u.job_id = j.job_id
     )
select employee_id, nvl(first_job_id, crt_job_id) as first_job_id,
       nvl(first_avg_salary, crt_avg_salary) as first_avg_sal,
       crt_job_id, crt_avg_salary, salary
from p
pivot ( min(job_id) as job_id, min(avg_salary) as avg_salary 
        for status in ('f' as first, 'c' as cRT)
      )
;
```

Comment: and he does it again! nice!